# Loop through all created fields and get the field type

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, fieldtypes

I want to show some input fields on frontend template form.

> Type of input is dependent on the type of fields selected on the backend.

**For example,** if the text field is selected in the backend I will create a field of `type="text"`. If a number field is selected I will show an input `type="number"` in the template.

I am trying to get `the field type` in my plugin.

```
$fields = Craft::$app->fields->getAllFields();
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
             $output[(int) $field->id] = array(
                'id'            => (int) $field->id,
                'handle'        => $field->handle,
                'name'          => $field->name,
                'instructions'  => $field->instructions
            );
        }
```

I checked the /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php but not found any method.

**Update:**
I checked a few files and i found a method which returns the string.

```
$field->displayName();
```

1. Number
2. Lightswitch

Is it the only way to get the type of field.

Answer (score 2):

Making sure you include `use craft\db\Query;` at the top of your Class, you can do something like this:

```php
$fields = (new Query())
    ->select(['id','handle','name','instructions','type'])
    ->from(['{{%fields}}'])
    ->all();

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $output[(int) $field['id']] = array(
        'id'            => (int) $field['id'],
        'handle'        => $field['handle'],
        'name'          => $field['name'],
        'instructions'  => $field['instructions'],
        'type'          => $field['type']
    );
}
```

Comment: @Oil

I tried the direct query as you suggested and i got the array https://pastebin.com/DW4D0pRE,

so i still need to pregmatch on type .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: As per field type I will show input of same type in frontend.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean field type or input type? Field type for me would be something like `craft\fields\PlainText` which the above gives you..?

Comment: @Oil I tried to update my question.By the way, your custom query is still helpful for me, as i don't think of query directly. +1

Comment: Oh I see! I may be wrong but I don't think you'll get that this way. Maybe make a custom map yourself?

Comment: Currently what I planned to get the field types of all the selected fields from my plugin settings page, than iterate over each field type and make relevant Html for frontend template. Chances are code may not be optimized initially, or extra lines of code are there 